# Laravel - Queue:work running in production but not processing jobs

Tags: laravel, supervisord, laravel-queue

I have set up a laravel project and want to send emails via the email queue.
I have set up supervisor on the server and started the processes.

However, the whenever I fire a laravel job and try to check on the `jobs` table, there is no entry. The log does not also have any remarks regarding the job. I have checked all ways to try and solve the problem but I am unable to do so. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Below is my configuration for the supervisor and jobs.

**Project Folder:** `/var/www/xyz.com`

Supervisor Configuration
**laravel-worker.conf**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/xyz.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 ->
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/xyz.com/storage/logs/laravel-queue.log
```

**Supervisorctl Output**

```
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00   RUNNING   pid 1545276, uptime 1:23:54
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01   RUNNING   pid 1545262, uptime 1:23:55
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_02   RUNNING   pid 1545277, uptime 1:23:54
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_03   RUNNING   pid 1545261, uptime 1:23:55
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_04   RUNNING   pid 1545294, uptime 1:23:53
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function GetDashboard(){  
    SendLeaveNotificationEmail::dispatch();
}
```

**SendLeaveNotificationEmail.php**

```
class SendLeaveNotificationEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public function __construct()
{
}

public function handle()
{
    Log::info("Job Dispatched");
}
}
```

When I check the log file for any message of `Job Dispatched`, it is always blank. This suggests that the job is not being fired/dispatched in the controller, or the supervisor is not processing the job. Kindly advise how I can solve this.

Comment: Might be something with your connection in .env or config/queue.php. is `QUEUE_CONNECTION` set to database in your .env? `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`

Comment: .env `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` and I have also run `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` but still it is not firing

Comment: The `Log::info("Job Dispatched");` line is writing to the default Laravel log file, not the `laravel-queue.log` file. Please check the default log file for the output.

Comment: Shut down your queue worker and then you can you check your jobs table to see if the jobs are being created.  Also try running with QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync which will just run each job as it is dispatched.  These are good ways to debug